# display a table of data with action to add new row

Tags: tables, data

i am making a dashboard for an app system that plays songs from soundcloud. **How would you recommend adding more songs to the list?**

I was thinking of having the form as another row at the bottom but the problem is that the soundcloud song url is the input, not the song name.

#### The table

[image: my table]

#### My current crappy solution

(after clicking a form slides out)

[image: current]

Comment: As we are on UX site, I feel obliged to remind, there is big probability that user do not want to input a song with an url. The user cognitive model would suggest adding by way of thinking (friends, similarity to other, search results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use a [+] button. No translations required and no text length issues. What does the form include?

[image]

A couple ideas for the form itself:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: the form includes a textfield to paste a soundcloud url, a play until datepicker and a rank

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion:

1. it should be as simple as one click.
2. if user wants to add song, he should do it without wondering - how to do it?
   so:
3. above list add textbox with label, inside this textbox (grayed) e.g: "put song URL to add to list, then press enter".
4. for other options You can display similar text boxes, but with default values. user can set it when creating new row, but optionally. later he can change it inside row.

that is how I want to use it - quick and simple :)